# Sitecore to WordPress migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, sitecore

I want my site to migrate from Sitecore to WordPress in such a way so that I can view the migrated page using specific page builder i.e Beaver Builder.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

I tried the default WordPress import export but facing difficulties getting content from Sitecore side.

I am expecting to get ways we can do this process.